# Make a lan connection between remote computers

Tags: network-programming

I want to create an application that makes some computers in lan of each other (Computers are not in a local network) but the are all connected to internet
I'm looking for a function for C++ or VB.NET to do it
My goal is to make them in lan of each other so if oen of them create a host in game,the others see his host and they can join him and play
If someone gives me an starting point it would be appreciated.

Comment: I have the impression that by the term 'make them in a LAN' you mean more than just 'have them see each other' which they already could over internet. If you are looking for some special feature like auto detection and the like, then say so!

Comment: Are you looking for a Virtual Private Network (VPN)?

Comment: @arkascha Bay saying in lan i mean that if anyone hosts a game in 'Local Area Netwok' mode,the other players see his game.Just like how Garena(www.garena.com) and GameRanger(www.gameranger.com) handles it

Comment: @Sudipta Chatterjee No,I don't want their IP to be changed

Comment: I am not aware of how Garena or GameRanger work, but I believe that you want your computers to be able to communicate with each other, right? Use a client-server setup and the server (publicly reachable) should be able to control the constituents

Comment: If you 'want something like how ... works' then you must explain what that something is. This is what I meant: explain what you really want, not some implicit mentioning of 'something a little like'....

Comment: @Sudipta Chatterjee Ok,I know i should do that but i don't know how,If you give me an msdn link i will handle it

Comment: @arkascha They connect all clients to their server and gives all clients a different virtual ip like 192.168.29.14 then the clients can see each others games

Comment: Ah, _that_ is something that can be answered. You are looking for the term 'VPN' then.

Comment: @arkascha Nice to hear that,Would you please point me to the right direction ? a function,an msdn link or ... ?

Comment: 'VPN' is a general term, a technology that implements what you are looking for. It is not an implementation specific term, so there is no function or library to point you towards. It is nothing MS specific, but general IT technology. Can be applied in general (typical case) or application internal (your case). Check wikipedia, I'd say, look for 'virtual private network'...

Comment: The problem is I dont want to give them a vpn connection and tell them to connect,I want to do it without they know it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just want to network with the clients, then use the Internet - it is the biggest "lan" there is.  Create a directory service that every client checks in with. In this directory service, each player that wants to host a game advertises themselves as a server; and clients can directly connect and play the game.